# Mongoid undefined method `field' for []:Array error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

Here's my model:

```
class Model
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :field_1, type: Integer
  field :field_2, type: Integer
  field :field_3, type: Integer
  field :field_4, type: Integer

  def success_rate
    return 0 if self.field_2.nil? || self.field_2 == 0
    return 0 if self.field_4.nil? || self.field_4 == 0
    (1.0 * field_4/field_3) * 100
  end
end
```

The error happens when I try to do the following:

```
aux = Model.where(field_1: user.id).first
```

However it works fine in my local machine, the issue is on my server.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the 'in' operator and wrapping the user.id in an array like this:
['user.id']?